# Sending mail from contact form with PHP and special characters

Tags: php, email

I'm afraid I'm not a programmer but still I'm trying to help a client fix an annoying issue with his site.

This is part of his `mailing.php`:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
```

But still, when viewed in his webmail, he get's `Ã¡ Ã±`, etc (even when hitting `view as html`).

I've done some searching, but either I'm applying the solutions poorly or something.

Comment: How do you know that's not the content being put into the email?

Comment: I'm testing it myself, I mail it to a gmail account and an account I can check with squirrelmail, gmail... awesome "á é í ó ú ñ" etc, but when I open it in squirrelmail... I keep getting those godawful characters. 
I've just rechecked if the charset is properly set in the php that has the form I capture the data from and it is.

Comment: Thank you for your time too Lucifer, decss solved the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diego Martinez, encoding of your letter depends on:

1. encoding of your script (f.e. sendmail.php)
2. encoding of text in variable, that you will send in letter (fe if your text)
3. headers in letter

to manipulate file (script) encoding use notepad++, it can convert your file (Encoding/Convert to ...) your file must have UTF-8 encoding

to change text encoding use [iconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php)

```
$text = iconv('utf-8', 'iso-8859-2', $text);
```

it will convert `$text` from `utf-8` to `iso-8859-2`

headers. i see, you know how to change it : )

Comment: Awesome, it absolutely did the trick!
Only modification is charset to iso-8859-1 in my scenario because -2 won't take "ñ".
Thank you very much for your time.